# Sum with reciprocal general term.

Tags: power-series, formal-power-series

Given a function $f$ expressed as follows as a formal power series (with $a_k\neq 0$)
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}a_kx^k,
$$
I was wondering if there is some way to relate the latter with the function $g$
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^k}{a_k}.
$$

Comment: Some simple cases suggest not.

 - $a_k=1$. Then $f(x)=g(x)$, for $|x|<1$.
 - $a_k=2^k$. Then $f(x)=1/(1-2x)$ for $|x|<1/2$ and $g(x) = 1/(1-x/2)$ for $|x|<2$
 - $a_k = k+1$. $f(x) = (1-x)^{-2}$ for $|x|<1$, $g(x) = -\log(1-x)/x$, for $x\in [-1,1)$.
 - $a_k = k!$. Then $f(x)$ is $1$ at $x=0$ and undefined elsewhere, whereas $g(x)=e^x$ for any $x$.

Comment: $g(x)$ probably isn't well defined as I expect the sum is divergent. In order for the sum for $f(x)$ to converge, $a_n$ needs to tend to $0$ which means that $\frac{1}{a_n}$ will tend to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: @K.defaoite I don't expect the radii of convergence to be the same; see my comment

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for a general description of the inverse under the [Hadamard product](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hadamard_theorem#Hadamard.27s_multiplication_theorem) of a known function, presumably in terms of standard operations like derivatives and reciprocals. There seems to be no hope for this. If it existed, surely the standard introductions would mention it (but of course it's very difficult to *prove* something like this doesn't exist).

Attempting to describe the Hadamard inverse of a rational function might be interesting.

Comment: Yeah I looked at a few cases where $a_k$ is a polynomial and the best I could get for $\sum_k 1/a_k x^k$ was a hypergeometric function depending on the degree of $a_k$. Interesting to know this operation has a name though.

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty to this answer because it gave me a way to investigate this further and provides information about the general case.

Answer (score 1):

The general situation is that the only relation between the two is $$f^{(n)}(0)g^{(n)}(0)=(n!)^2$$

Comment: Hmm, would you mind fleshing this out?

Comment: @Integrand the $n$th derivative of $f$, evaluated at $x=0$, is $n!a_n$, and the $n$th derivative of $g$, evaluated at $x=0$, is $n!a_n^{-1}$. So, the product is $(n!)^2$.

Comment: Is that what you wanted, @Integrand ?